# How to add a wallpaper/image in the background page in google appmaker?

Tags: google-app-maker

I need to add a particular wallpaper in the background page of my app to make the app look more colorful and beautiful. Is there any way?

The problem is that once you add an image to a page then it does not allow you to place another widget over it or cover it. It always aligns it horizontally or vertically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty much basic css. I'd recommend you to look [over this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) to learn more. So, in appmaker, if you want to apply the background image to a page do this:

### The CSS

1.) First, select the root widget of the page you are interested.
[image]

2.) Now, that you have the page selected, let's move to the style editor. Once there, on the **Page Style** section just type a "."(period, dot) and wait for the suggestions to appear. The first suggestion is what you need, so just press enter or select it with your cursor.

[image]

3.) Now that you have selected the element with a css selector, you can apply styling. For the background, you need to do this:

```
.app-myTestingPage-myPage {
  background: url("url-to-picture");
}
```

[image]

In the above example, `url-to-picture` represents that, a url to a an image, preferably if it is served over **https**.

### The URL

I know two ways in which you can get the background image url. The first one is to use any image url you find on the internet or a url hosted in your own server or cdn. The second way is to upload the image to appmaker resources and use that url. If you choose the latter, then do the following:

1.) Go to the app settings.

2.) Click on **Resources**

3.) Drop your image file in the respected area or click the button to browse

[image]

Once the resource finishes uploading, you can click the copy icon to copy the url to the resource and you can use that in your page css as the background url.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this using CSS in your style editor. Either in your 'Page style' or 'Global style' depending on if you only want the background image to a specific page or be available throughout your application. You will want to declare a custom class or reference the specific elements that you want to render the background image in.

For a specific element:

```
.app-YourPage1-YourPanel, .app-YourPage2-YourPanel {
  background-image: url(YourImageURL);
}
```

For a global style, create a class and for each element you want the background image applied you would add that class to the 'Styles' section of that element(widget):

```
.YourPanelClass {
  background-image: url(YourImageURL);
}
```

Either way I highly suggest you do a search on 'html background image' so you can read up on additional options such as repeating the image to fill space and such.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and additional suggestions.